# How to schedule a model to run at a certain time?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, modelbuilder

I'm trying to schedule a model to run at a certain time and have found this [ESRI Blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/) which is providing a good start. What I can't figure out though is where in the [importToolbox function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ImportToolbox/018v0000005z000000/) I tell it which model/tool within the toolbox to run? I have a toolbox that has about a dozen tools/models within it and I just want to run 1 of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Blog Post that you provided there is this python snippet:

```
import arcpy
import os
from datetime import datetime

# Import the toolbox containing the model.  This toolbox
#  has an alias of "gpxtools"
#
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"c:\importgpx\myGPXstuff.tbx")

# Run the model.  The model has two parameters, the input
#  .gpx file and the feature class to update
#
arcpy.ImportGPX_gpxtools(r"c:\ftp\inbox\datadrop.gpx",
                         r"c:\ftp\server.sde\gpx_tracks")

# Now that the input gpx file has been processed, rename it
#   to have the date and time.
#
os.rename(r"c:\ftp\inbox\datadrop.gpx",
          r"c:\ftp\inbox\datadrop{}.gpx".format(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y%m%d"))
```

The Line

```
arcpy.ImportGPX_gpxtools(r"c:\ftp\inbox\datadrop.gpx",
                             r"c:\ftp\server.sde\gpx_tracks")
```

is where the tool is executed.
After importing the toolbox, you just execute one of the tools within the toolbox, with "arcpy.FULL_TOOL_NAME(Parameters)

See ArcGIS Help:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000000n000000

Comment: thanks. I was confused by that line and it being related to something else. works perfectly.